# Slow mongodb query on changing sort direction

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization

I have MongoDB 4.4 cluster and a database with collection of 200k documents and 55 indexes for different queries.

The following query:

```
db.getCollection('tasks').find({
        "customer": "gZuu5ZptDEtC6dq2Z",
        "finished": true,
        "$or": [
            {
                "scoreCalculated": {
                    "$exists": true
                },

            },
            {
                "workflowProcessed": {
                    "$exists": true
                },

            }
        ]
    }).sort({
        "scoreCalculated": -1,
       "workflowProcessed": -1,
       "createdAt": -1
    })
```

is executed at average of less than 1 second. [Explain](https://jsonblob.com/884053528470110208).

But if I change sort direction to

```
.sort({
        "scoreCalculated": 1,
       "workflowProcessed": 1,
       "createdAt": 1
    })
```

the execution time grows to several seconds (up to 10). [Explain](https://jsonblob.com/884054683774369792).

The first explain shows that apiGetTasks index is used. But it has ascending sort and I don't get why it is not used when I turn sort direction to ascending. Adding same index with descending sort doesn't change anything.

Could you please help me to understand why the second query is so slow?

Comment: could you please show me the index apiGetTasks

Comment: Sure @MoussabKbeisy `{
    "scoreCalculated" : 1,
    "workflowProcessed" : 1,
    "createdAt" : 1
}`

Comment: You can know why the query is taking longer by running the explain (with 'executionStats' mode) on _both_ the sort operations. See which index is being used for the sort. What are the other operations in the query? These influence what index is used or not used.

Comment: @prasad_ I've attached explain made with 'allPlansExecution' for each query to question.

Comment: According to your explain results, the index is used for sorting - in both cases.

Comment: I have doubts the problem is because of all query sort, in the first query , it was `finished:true` which is the same index direction , in the second one it is not the same, I need you to try to execute the second query , but just remove `finished:true` , and tell me the result

Comment: @MoussabKbeisy it is still slow without `finished: true` http://jsonblob.com/884364359976108032.

Comment: @prasad_ I don't argue I'm just asking why second query is 10 times slower

Comment: How many documents are there for sorting (after the filter)?

Comment: @prasad_ approximately 100k

Comment: Without index how does it sort?

Comment: @prasad_ I have no idea how to check that

Answer (score 0):

Please share the indexes.
55 indexes are way too much you should decrease it because it can harm your performance (every time you want to use an index you need to load it to RAM instead letting Mongo utilize the RAM in order to optimize queries).
Moreover, the number of total exterminated docs is 210780 which is all your collection. So you need to rethink how to build efficiently indexes that help you optimize queries.
Read Mongo indexes docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)